# How do I create a new dict of dicts from a dict with nested dicts in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am starting with a dict received from an api

```
start_dict = { 
    "a": 795, 
    "b": 1337, 
    "c": [
        {
            "d1": 2,
            "d2": [
                 {
                      "e1": 4
                 }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

I need to create a separate dict from that dict. That has each of the keys and value separated by their key and value into there own dict. While keeping the nested dicts intact.

```
values =
{
"fields": [
  {
    "element_name": "a",
    "value": 795
  },
  {
    "element_name": "b",
    "value": 1337
  },
  { 
    "element_name": "c",
    "value": [
            {
                 "element_name": "d1",
                 "value": 2
            },
            {
                 "element_name": "d2",
                 "value" : [
                          {
                               "element_name": "e1",
                               "value": 4
                          }
                      ]
            ]
       }
    ]
  }
```

The actual dict is quite a bit larger but there are no more then one two deep nested dicts in the original but many single nested dicts. This is the only way the api will accept new data so I am kinda stuck until I figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am quite new to Python (3 Weeks) lol so if this is something simple please don't be to harsh.

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? Put some code in the question...

Comment: Your `c` value is a bit of an enigma. You have a list with a single dictionary in that list, but the resulting output is a list with the key-value pairs from that one dictionary transformed to separate dictionaries. What should happen if there are more than one element in that `c` list? What if there are more lists contained, or objects that are not dictionaries? The same applies to `d2`.

Comment: My solution below results in a *nested* list, as the single dictionary is transformed to a list of key-value dictionaries. If there is more than one dictionary, that means each of those becomes a separate list inside the master `c` list. Any other object types are also handled properly this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the output with a recursive function:

```
def transform(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        return [transform(v) for v in ob]
    elif not isinstance(ob, dict):
        return ob
    return [{'element_name': k, 'value': transform(v)}
            for k, v in ob.items()]

values = {'fields': transform(start_dict)}
```

so each `key, value` pair is transformed to a `{'element_name': key, 'value': value}` dictionary in a list, where any value that is itself a list or dictionary is transformed by a recursive call.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def transform(ob):
...     if isinstance(ob, list):
...         return [transform(v) for v in ob]
...     elif not isinstance(ob, dict):
...         return ob
...     return [{'element_name': k, 'value': transform(v)}
...             for k, v in ob.items()]
...
>>> start_dict = {
...     "a": 795,
...     "b": 1337,
...     "c": [
...         {
...             "d1": 2,
...             "d2": [
...                  {
...                       "e1": 4
...                  }
...         ]
...         }
...     ]
...     }
>>> pprint({'fields': transform(start_dict)})
{'fields': [{'element_name': 'a', 'value': 795},
            {'element_name': 'c',
             'value': [[{'element_name': 'd1', 'value': 2},
                        {'element_name': 'd2',
                         'value': [[{'element_name': 'e1', 'value': 4}]]}]]},
            {'element_name': 'b', 'value': 1337}]}
```

Comment: So when working with nested dicts you need a recursive function so that when it comes across a nested dict it can loop back into the function and cont. working on the dict in side the dict? Thank you So much for your help it is much appreciated!!!!

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to use recursion; I just find it easier to write a recursive function for this. You could use a stack and a loop too.